# Does anyone know how to nest separate raise notice?

Tags: postgresql, raise, raiserror

I'm using plpgsql and I have no clue to nest raise notices i.e.

```
raise notice 'Show id variable is: ', id_variable;
```

But I don't know how to show two variables in the same line, like:

```
raise notice 'X variable is: ', x , 'and Y variable is: ' y;
```

I obiously declared them in the **declare section.** Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think it's `raise notice 'X variable is: % and Y variable is: %', x, y;`

Comment: It worked! thx a lot.